# Phoenix channel's socket keeps getting closed in distributed cluster environment

Tags: kubernetes, elixir, phoenix-framework, channel

I followed [this](https://blog.polyscribe.io/a-complete-guide-to-deploying-elixir-phoenix-applications-on-kubernetes-part-1-setting-up-d88b35b64dcd) series of articles to create a deployment at Google Cloud. Everything is working as expected, except phoenix channels.

No errors on the backend side. On Javascript frontend I am getting first channel ERROR and then the socket CLOSES on frontend while using channels. And this keeps repeating endlessly in an interval of 10–20 secs.

```
CHANNEL ERROR!
SOCKET CLOSE!
CHANNEL ERROR!
SOCKET CLOSE!
```

From this code:

```
socket.connect()
socket.onError( e => console.log("SOCKET ERROR", e) )
socket.onClose( e => console.log("SOCKET CLOSE", e))
channel = socket.channel("note:" + noteId, {})
channel.onError( e => console.log("CHANNEL ERROR!", e) )
channel.onClose( e => console.log("CHANNEL CLOSED!", e) )
```

I need help to debug this and figure out where this problem is originating from. Please let me know if any piece of code is needed and I will update the question with that code. Its been a week now. :(

Thanks a lot!

(No problem when run locally)

**UPDATE:** The only difference I am seeing is that on local server, phoenix.js is continuously sending heartbeat but this is not happening on server.

**UPDATE:**

```
---- my-ingress.yaml ----
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    # ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-ingress-ip
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: apiv2.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service-nodeport
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /.well-known/acme-challenge
        backend:
          serviceName: kube-lego-gce
          servicePort: 8080
  tls:
  - secretName: my-secret-tls-7
    hosts:
    - apiv2.example.com
```

This is [ingress file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) I am using and also using [kube-lego](https://github.com/jetstack/kube-lego) with it.

**UPDATE:** I implemented this code (I checked frames in dev tools, they were being sent). But still... its giving SOCKER ERROR. May be issue is not with sending hearbeats.

```
const HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS = 5000
socket.onOpen(() => {
      clearInterval(this.heartbeatTimer);
      this.heartbeatTimer = setInterval(() => { 
        return socket.push({ 
          topic: "phoenix", 
          event: "heartbeat", 
          payload: {}, 
          ref: socket.makeRef(), 
        }); 
      }, 
        HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS
      );
    })
```

Comment: Is remote running HTTP, not HTTPS? Have you changed the endpoint in your javascript? Please share the javascript, it’s definitely an issue with a wrong endpoint or like.

Comment: Remote is running HTTPS. And locally also, I am running HTTPS. socketUrl = `wss://${backendIp}/usersocket` is how I am declaring the websocket url, if thats what you asking for. Let me know if you mean something else. Thanks!

Comment: PORT might differ.

Comment: But if PORT would have been different, application wont work at all. Right? And the application is working fine despite this issue. Still I will double check and let you know. I mean phoenix channels are also working. It's just that they get disconnected and reconnected quite often.

Comment: I have not specified the port anywhere in the javascript, I checked. That's because I am connecting to 443 I guess. And I am using kubernetes ingress service and kube-lego to support ssl. I am updating the answer with the content of that file.

Comment: OK, I believe there is only one possibility left: somehow the normal timeout of 30secs for server socket has decreased in your case. Sending `heartbeat` is mandatory and is up to the client script: otherwise the server decides the client has died and disconnects the socket. I doubt this has anything to do with kubernetes.

Comment: I checked, SOCKET ERROR comes every 30secs. I decreased the `opts.heartbeatIntervalMs` to 10000 and then I verified that hearbeats were sent exactly after every 10 secs. But still after every 30secs SOCKET ERROR comes up. :(

Comment: Do you send `heartbeat` from your client script manually? You should do. I could provide a snippet if it helps (though it’s trivial, just a recurring `setInterval`.)

Comment: Please do link me to that script. In meanwhile, I will try it on my own. BTW, what's the difference between sending it manually and automatically by phoenix.

Comment: Phoenix _does not send_ anything. It’s the client side who confirms it’s still alive. Phoenix is the server side, it’s only responds to `heartbeat` and does not drop/close the connection if the client is still alive. `onConnOpen` handler should contain smth like: `clearInterval(this.heartbeatTimer); this.heartbeatTimer = setInterval(function () { return this.push({ topic: "phoenix", event: "heartbeat", payload: {}, ref: this.pendingHeartbeatRef }); }, this.heartbeatIntervalMs);`

Comment: I updated my question with the reply.

Comment: Could it be something to do with multiple nodes of elixir app on the server? I have only a single node locally. That's the only difference I can see.

Comment: Honestly, I dunno. I am still thinking about this, but I doubt I understand what could cause this behavior; I never experienced something similar. My last wild guess would be: could you try to create a brand new empty phoenix project, enable websockets and deploy it to check if the problem is indeed environment specific, or still the project specific?

Comment: Hmm. I guess that is the only way left. I will do that once I get time. In the meantime if you get any idea, do let me know. And many many thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Sure I will; welcome, sorry for not being helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to increase the response timeout for your [backend service](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#timeouts_and_retries) on GCP.

By default, the timeout was set at 30sec and was causing the same problem for me.

Comment: This finally solved the problem. BTW what timeout did you choose to use for your service? I am now using timeout of 200secs, after which it still disconnects. And I am pretty sure that heartbeats are getting sent fine. Still it gets disconnects and reconnects after the timeout. Is there a way to stop this. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: I used whatever max value it allows. I forget what it is. Try entering a really large number and maybe it'll tell you the cap.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that.